# Setup functionbeat to send output to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat, logstash-configuration

I am setting up functionbeat with logstash as output. But when I run `./functionbeat setup -e`, I get following error

```
Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
```

My functionbeat.yml file is as follows:

```
###################### Functionbeat Configuration Example #######################
# Configure which S3 endpoint should we use.
functionbeat.provider.aws.endpoint: "s3.amazonaws.com"
# Configure which S3 bucket we should upload the lambda artifact.
functionbeat.provider.aws.deploy_bucket: "functionbeat-advertising"
functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
  # Define the list of function availables, each function required to have a unique name.
  # Create a function that accepts events coming from cloudwatchlogs.
  - name: cloudwatchlogging
    enabled: true
    type: cloudwatch_logs

    # Description of the method to help identify them when you run multiples functions.
    description: "lambda function for cloudwatch logs"
    # List of cloudwatch log group registered to that function.
    triggers:
      - log_group_name: /aws/lambda/my_log_group_name

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["my_logstash_host"]
# ================================= Processors =================================
# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
setup.template.enabled: false
setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

I have disabled ilm but still I am getting

> Index management requested

error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-installation-configuration.html#setup-assets), a connection to elasticsearch is *required* if you want to run `./functionbeat setup -e`.

You can [load the template manually](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-template.html#load-template-manually), but that still requires direct connectivity to the elasticsearch host, you cannnot load it via logstash.

Comment: The template is already setup. I just want to stream logs from Cloudwatch to Elastic cloud via Logstash

Comment: Sound like you want to deploy functionbeat, not setup functionbeat. You deploy functionbeat to the cloud service (e.g. AWS) as described by the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-installation-configuration.html#functionbeat-deploying), and then the cloud will invoke the functionbeat when the trigger conditions are met.